# How to use rbenv to change ruby versions in a shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, rbenv

I have a shell script that is changing between different directories, setting up various projects. Each project has a `.ruby-version` file.

How can I get rbenv to change to the appropriate ruby version in each directory?

I have something like this right now:

```
  Dir.chdir(target) do
    run('rbenv install -s')
    run('eval "$(rbenv init -)" ' \
        '&& gem install bundler ' \
        '&& rbenv rehash ' \
        '&& bundle install')
  end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.0
1 gem installed
Your Ruby version is 2.2.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5
Command `eval "$(rbenv init -)" && gem install bundler && rbenv rehash && bundle install` failed with status 18
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a Ruby version lock in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: system("command here")?